# How to reuse initialized Java class I call in the karate feature background in every scenario without refreshing it each time?

Tags: karate

In the background of the feature file, I am calling a Java class and initializing it with the two services provided below. This allows me to use the encryption methods within this class. However, since these services are in the background for every scenario, they are repeatedly posted, leading to a performance loss in Gatling performance tests. I am aware that it is normal for the background to be reloaded in every scenario.

How can I ensure that this Java class is called and initialized only once in the background? I know the concept

If I don't call the RequestPublicKey and SessionRegister services to initialize the Java class, the methods within the Java class return null.

I tried calling with call, callsingle, callonce from different features, but the methods returned null. I attempted to perform these actions with JS, but couldn't achieve the desired result

This is my background :

```
Background:
* def conf = call read('../karate-config.js')
* url conf.whiteboxUrlUat
* def requestFile = read('data.json')

#Database Configurations
* def dbJsFile = call read('../database-configurations.js')
* def dbConfigurations = dbJsFile.sqlServerConfigurations
* def DbUtils = Java.type('testrails.DbUtils')
* def db = new DbUtils(dbConfigurations)

Given path 'api/SecureChannel/RequestPublicKey'
* def requestBody = requestFile.requestPublicKey
Given request requestBody
When method POST
* java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
Then print response
* def secureChannelPublicKey = response.PublicKey
* def scrChnl = Java.type('testrails.SecureChannel')
* def scr = new scrChnl(secureChannelPublicKey,"PB10203S60738","")
* match response.ErrorCode == 0

Given path 'api/SecureChannel/SessionRegister'
* def requestBody = requestFile.sessionRegister
Given request requestBody
* def sessionRegisterEncData = scr.generateSessionRegisterEncData()
* requestBody.EncData = sessionRegisterEncData
When method POST
Then print response
* scr.decryptData(response.EncData)
* match response.ErrorCode == 0
```

This is one of my scenarios:
As seen in this scenario, I am using the methods with "scr."

Scenario: Register

```
* url conf.mposEntMainUrl
Given path 'api/MainAppExternal/Register'
* def requestBody = requestFile.register
* def requestBodyConvertString = scr.mapToString(requestBody)
* def secureContentOlustur = scr.initSecureRequest(requestBodyConvertString,"PB99999999999")
Then print secureContentOlustur.secureContent
* def secureBody = requestFile.register2
* secureBody.SecureContent = secureContentOlustur.secureContent
Given request secureBody
When method POST
Then print response
Then print scr.generateRandomAesKey()
* match response.Code == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a "normal" Java singleton or your custom logic. Something like this:

```
static boolean initialized;

static void init() {
  if (!initialized) {
    initialized = true;
    doWork();
  }
}
```

Now you can call `MyJavaClass.init()` any number of times.

Comment: When I establish a singleton structure like this, how should I design the services called in the background? To prevent the services called in the background from being executed more frequently than other services in Gatling, how can I call these services outside of the background in a way that allows me to initialize my Java class?

Comment: @HakanAras honestly karate.callSingle() is the right answer then, I really don't know why it doesn't work for you, maybe you need to focus on that. but if you know how to make a call to that service from java, that may be a solution

Comment: I checked again the background for 'CallSingle' and I read carefully the Karate documents again. I realized that I was trying to access the methods using the wrong approach. When I checked and tried again, I got the result I wanted. Thank you very much for your support.